# How to precompile SCIP for visual stdio

Tags: c++, scip

Sorry for my poor English, I am kind of being new to the SCIP. I precompile the SCIP with minGW as http://scip.zib.de said. But when I want to link SCIP to visual stdio,there's only .a without .lib or .dll that I can use. I want to know how to generate .lib for Visual C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use CMake to compile the SCIP Opt Suite as explained [here](http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/CMAKE.php) or you just [download the installer](http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=SCIPOptSuite-5.0.1-win64-VS15.exe) that includes the libraries and executables.

Comment: Thanks for you help sincerely，I have already deleted my answer，it's bold and thoughtless.